# Problem with asp.net custom hander

Tags: asp.net

ive written a custom http handler and its in app_code. It's just a website so code is not being compiled into a dll. I've written the handler and its signature looks like this...

```
namespace MicrotanksWebsite
{
    public class RssHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

    }

}
```

The error i'm getting is:

> Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MicrotanksWebsite.RssHandler'.

the web config looks like this

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" type="MicrotanksWebsite.RssHandler" path="*.rss" />
</httpHandlers>
```

any ideas?

Comment: What happens if you specify an assembly?  `type="MicrotanksWebsite,MicrotanksWebsite.RssHandler`

Comment: I guess it has to be type="MicrotanskWebsite.RssHandler, App_Code"

Comment: For the record, whether you put it in a dll or whether the ASP.NET framework compiles it to a dll, I assure you the IIS environment only uses the dll version of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Been there...
If your handler file is not in the root folder of the application (sub folder or something) iis requires you to copy your dll with `YourNameSpace.YourHandlerType` to that folder.

Comment: There is no dll, the project is a website and there is no single output to a dll. If you navigate to the folder in which the website runs, its structured just as the project is, App_Code has files in it that you can edit on the fly, as well as all asp.net pages... trying the suggested type="MicrotanksWebsite,MicrotanksWebsite.RssHandler didnt go anywhere nore was the MicrotanksWebsite.RssHandler, App_Code

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the assembly:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" type="MicrotanksWebsite.RssHandler, MyAssembly" path="*.rss" />
</httpHandlers>
```

Comment: I've switched the project from a asp .net website to a asp .net web application(which builds a dll) and was able to get it to work. I'm still not sure how it's possible when no dll in built like a asp .net website project.

Comment: Good - I never use the "website" project type.

Answer (score 0):

I've switched the project from a asp .net website to a asp .net web application(which builds a dll) and was able to get it to work. I'm still not sure how it's possible when no dll in built like a asp .net website project.